# Popup is not getting shown - bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap popup is not showing up on click. Only "modal-open class" and "modal-backdropin" open in browser. But popup window is not showing.

Here is my code

```
<script>
    $(function () {
            $('#signup').on('click', function () {
                $(this).attr('data-target') ;
                $('#myModal').load('register.html');{
                    $(this).modal({ show: true });
                };
            });
      });
    </script>
<a href="register.html" id="signup" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Sign Up</a>
```

Comment: Error in this line `$('#myModal').load('register.html');{
                    $(this).modal({ show: true });
                };`

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: Popup window is not showing on click because I am calling popup content remotely(from other file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the target in a `variable` and use it in the `load` function, and also note that an extra semicolon removed from  load('register.html')'**;**' from your original code

```
   $(function () {
            $('#signup').on('click', function () {
                var target = $(this).attr('data-target') ;
             $("#myModal").load(target, function() { 
               $("#myModal").modal("show"); 
             });
            });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would change the link to this...

```
<a data-content="register.html" id="signup" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Sign Up</a>
```

Followed by  jQuery like this...

```
(function()
{   
    $('#signup').on('click', function()
    {
        var target = $(this).data('content');            
        $("#myModal > .modal-dialog > .modal-content > .modal-body").load(target, function()
        {
            $(this).modal("show"); 
        });
    });
})();
```